# Reshaping or "concatenating" a tensor along an axis

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor, `t`, of the following shape: `torch.Size([280, 4, 768])`.

What I want is to achieve, effectively, concatenation along the second axis, resulting in `torch.Size([280, 3072])`.

I know that I can for instance, do:

`torch.cat((x[:, -4, :], x[:, -3, :], x[:, -2, :], x[:, -1, :]), dim=1)`

but is there a nicer way of writing this?

How do I achieve reshaping along the second axis without messing up my values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can apply a straight forward [`reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.reshape.html):

```
>>> x.reshape(len(x), -1)
```